# SQL LEFT JOIN EXCLUDE TWO RECORDS FROM SECOND TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying LEFT join and also wants to exclude records from second table, if status=Yes. But when I use LEFT join, it gives all the records from table1 without excluding the records from table2 whose status is 'Yes'.

```
Table1
--------------------------------
id  date
--------------------------------
1   01/09/2020
2   02/09/2020
3   03/09/2020
4   04/09/2020
5   05/09/2020


Table2
--------------------------------
id  date          status
--------------------------------
1   01/09/2020    Yes
2   02/09/2020    Yes
3   03/09/2020
```

Desired result

```
--------------------------------
id  date
--------------------------------
3   03/09/2020   
4   04/09/2020   
5   05/09/2020
```

Excludes  id 1,2 because table2 has status="yes".

I know my SQL syntax is wrong.  Please advise  the correct syntax:

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.date
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (select table2.id, table2.date from table2 where status!='Yes') as table2
ON table1.id=table2.id and table1.date = table2.date
```

Comment: Please post your desired result. It will useful for correct answer

Comment: Hi Slava, added desired result.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the correct conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.date = t1.date
WHERE COALESCE(t2.status, '') <> 'Yes'
```

or:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.date = t1.date
WHERE t2.status IS NULL OR t2.status <> 'Yes'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=090015c6e7e1ac4d7ebe2ebdfeaf7b07).
Results:

```
> id | date      
> -: | :---------
>  3 | 03/09/2020
>  4 | 04/09/2020
>  5 | 05/09/2020
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got my desired result. I would like to more about WHERE COALESCE(t2.status, '') <> 'Yes'. How does it function?

Comment: COALESCE() returns the 1st non null of its arguments or null if they are all null. So in this case it returns t2.status if it is not null or '' (an empty string).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *filter* records, then use an inner join, not an outer join:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date
WHERE t2.status <> 'Yes';
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, I think `NOT EXISTS` is the best approach:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date and
                        t2.status = 'Yes'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried this syntax but unfortunately no success. It gives only record no. 3 from table2 but I want records: 3, 4, 5 from table1. I have added the desired result in my post, please review.

Comment: @awan . . . The sample data is a big help.  I think you just want `not exists`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by use `NOT EXISTS` condition like:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.id = Table1.id AND Table2.status = 'Yes'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write the solution this way:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.date
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table2.status = 'Yes'
WHERE Table2.id IS NULL
```

As you know, a left outer join returns NULL for rows of the right table if there is no match. If the match condition includes `status='Yes'` then rows with other status values are not a match.

Then the WHERE clause restricts results to rows of Table1 that had no match.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative query is the following (since i can't really understand why it is needed to join on id also):

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`,`t1`.`date` FROM `Table1` `t1` 
LEFT JOIN `Table2` `t2` ON `t1`.`date`=`t2`.`date`
WHERE `t2`.`status` <> 'Yes' OR `t2`.`date` IS NULL;
```

Here is a relevant [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c9906/6)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id 
WHERE t2.status != 'Yes' 
GROUP BY t1.id;
```